# Using sapply recursively until value is not NA in R

Tags: r, sapply

I have a dataframe `df` with a simple conversation flow (conversation  `partner.id` and `conversation.label`). These data should represent the type of question asked by the `admin` role and the answer given by the `interviewee`.

```
df = data.frame('partner.id' = c('admin', 'interviewee', 'interviewee', 'admin', 'interviewee', 'admin', 'interviewee', 'interviewee', 'admin', 'interviewee')
            , 'conversation.label' = c('intro', NA, NA, 'intro', NA, 'open', NA, NA, 'closed', NA))

    partner.id conversation.label
1        admin              intro
2  interviewee               <NA>
3  interviewee               <NA>
4        admin              intro
5  interviewee               <NA>
6        admin               open
7  interviewee               <NA>
8  interviewee               <NA>
9        admin             closed
10 interviewee               <NA>
```

I want to set the interviewee conversation label (all `NA`) to the preceding one of the admin (i.e. that the interviewee label gets the label of the question asked by the admin):

```
    partner.id conversation.label
1        admin              intro
2  interviewee              intro (HERE!)
...
```

To do this, I used `sapply` recursively like:

```
df$conversation.label[2 : length(df$conversation.label)] = sapply(seq(2, length(df$conversation.label)), function(i){
  print(is.na(df$conversation.label[i]))
  if(is.na(df$conversation.label[i])){
    df$conversation.label[i] = df$conversation.label[i-1]
  } else {
    df$conversation.label[i] = df$conversation.label[i]
  }
})
```

This works fine if there if there are no two `NAs` after one another.

The script above outputs:

```
    partner.id conversation.label
1        admin              intro
2  interviewee              intro
3  interviewee               <NA>
4        admin              intro
5  interviewee              intro
6        admin               open
7  interviewee               open
8  interviewee               <NA>
9        admin             closed
10 interviewee             closed
```

How can I rewrite this script so that it does the recursive part until the `conversation.label` is not `NA` instead of just going back `[n-1]`?

Comment: Have you tried `zoo:na.locf` ?

Comment: @user2100721 Just looked up `na.locf`, haven't heard of it before. How would I implement it? I guess it's in the line with `df$conversation.label[i] = df$conversation.label[i-1]` but `df$conversation.label[i] = na.locf(df$conversation.label[i])` does not work. Ideas (maybe post as answer)?

Comment: This solves my problem: `df$conversation.label` = `na.locf(df$conversation.label, na.rm = F)`. Since this was your idea, I'd be happy to accept it as an answer if you post it as such.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't check earlier and also sorry for inconvenience.